# javascript problems with array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, echo

i've to write something like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("elName[]")[0].value=Array('val1','val2','val3', etc);
```

My problem is inside the "Array" elements, because i have to write inside some values from an array already initialized

```
var val_vec= new Array(<?php echo $count ?>);
```

i've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
document.getElementsByName("elName")[0].value=Array(
            for(var i=0; i< <?php echo $count ?> ; i++)
            {
                document.write('"'+ val_vec[i] + '"');
                if(i!=<?php echo $count-1 ?>)
                    document.write(',');
            });
```

the 'if' condition it is writed because of all commas betweens 'vars' (the last comma must not be written!)

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax makes no sense whatsoever. Using a `for` loop inside of `Array(…)`, that is just complete nonsense.

If you want to get all array values as a comma-separated string, then simply use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Or, if your question is about how to get a PHP array of values “transferred” to a JavaScript variable (really hard to tell what you actually want to know) – use PHP’s `json_encode`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will consider it about using .join() next time. (i'm not a expert - in fact i didn't know about it's existence before today.)